# Anime about past life and a moon base

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw this around 1997.
I think most of the main characters in this movie are teenagers. They meet a younger kid named S-kun. They find out (maybe S-kun told them) that in a past life they had worked together in a moon base. S-kun died and reincarnated last, which is why he's now younger than the others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely *[Please Save My Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Please_Save_My_Earth)*

> The story centers around high-school student Alice Sakaguchi, her seven-year-old next door neighbor, Rin Kobayashi who attends elementary school, and five other teenage students who have recurring collective dreams about a group of alien scientists stationed on the moon observing and collecting data about the Earth.
>
> Initially, when Alice learns that her classmates Jinpachi and Issei have been having common recurring dreams since middle school, she thinks nothing of it until one day she has one of these "moon dreams" herself. Because of the nature of these dreams, the way Issei always dreams as the same person, and Jinpachi as well, now that Alice has provided a third perspective, they start to believe that people who dream as the other four scientists in their "moon dreams" can each be found.
>
> Almost like playing a simple game, the three make plans to seek these other people out in the hopes of making sense of these dreams. After a suggestion from Issei, and a little bit of time and luck, they are finally able to make contact with the other four people. But as the six teenagers and one child start to piece together the chronology and content of their dreams, they began to realize that their "dreams" are not simply dreams, but rather suppressed memories of their past incarnations that ended tragically. And now, as their "game" begins to unravel, the kids must strive to come to terms with what happened in their past lives, as they struggle to prevent their past incarnations' rivalries, jealousies, and dubious actions from taking over their new ones.

"S-Kun" is Rin Kobayashi as per [this review](http://www.cjas.org/%7Eechen/articles/fall95/09_16a.html):

> Rin-kun/S-kun is an adult in a child's body. He feels more emotion over what happened on the moon than the other six do.

Indeed, he is younger than the rest due the circumstances of his prior life, where he died nine years later than the others.

> Shion was the last of the moon team to die. He had been inoculated against the virus that was killing them, so lived alone for nine years after Mokuren died. He was unable to commit suicide because Mokuren warned him that people who commit suicide will not be reincarnated. This is why Rin is nine years younger than everyone else. After Mokuren's death, Shion went insane. The cold, ruthless side that Rin sometimes displays is Shion's, and his plan is to make Shukaido suffer.

### Ad for Engish dub

Found with a search for `anime "s-kun" moon base`